# How to properly Tar and gzip a Jupyter notebook and relevant csv files?

Tags: csv, command-line, jupyter-notebook, tar

I have to send a Jupyter notebook with an analysis to a colleague. It was asked I tar and gzip the files. The notebook uses 3 csv data sets that are present in the same folder as the notebook.
I have never done this before and my background is mathematics not programming, so if this answer is obvious please forgive.

In the notebook I load all the datasets by reading them in from a folder on my computer (the same folder the notebook is in and that I will be tar balling). How can I tar the files so that my code runs smoothly in the notebook. Or do I have to edit the call on the data set in the notebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply compress/zip the parent folder of the notebook and the 3 data files.

If the folder structure was like this:

```
- Parent folder
    - notebook
    - csv1
    - csv2
    - csv3
```

You would want to simply compress/zip the "Parent folder" to achieve your question.

Please let me know if you have any more questions!